# How to move Site Action menu contents to a slideout menu?

Tags: 2010

I know that the default behavior is to have the site actions menu appear when you click on the  "Site Actions" text in the upper left part of the screen

What I am doing is creating a group of tabs for navigation on the left of the screen.  When clicked their contents slideout from the left and are revealed.  I was able to accomplish this with the Quick Launch so that the Quick Launch is essentially hidden until you hover over the tab I created and then it slides out from the left.  I want to perform the same functionality with the Site Actions Menu where there would be a tab on the left that when hovered/clicked the site action menu reveals itself from the left.

If there was a way to put the contents of the Site Actions Menu in a `<div>` I can perform the rest through jquery.  It just seems the site actions menu acts a bit differntly than what I am expecting.  Any input would be appreciated.